# How to tell if my OpenPGP public key is self-signed?

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg

I recently read:

> You should sign your PGP public key immediately after generating your public/private key-pair.

And now I wonder how I can check whether I already did that. So my question is: how can I tell if my own pgp public key is self-signed or not?

I'm using GnuPG/MacGPG2 v2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### OpenPGP Self Signatures

Self-signatures are applied on user IDs and subkeys, and make it obvious to anybody else that the ID or subkey *really*  have really been added by yourself. User IDs and subkeys *not selfsigned* could have been added by anybody and uploaded to the key servers.

Usually, self-signatures are created automatically by GnuPG, so you don't need to care about anything.

### Checking for Self Signatures

Using the terminal, checking for self signatures is achieved very easily. Self-signatures are listed among the others, so all you need to do is filter for user IDs, subkeys and their respective next lines (which should contain the self signature).

```
gpg --list-sigs [key-id] |grep -EA1 '^(sub|uid)'
```

If you have a user ID or subkey which does not have a signature issued by your own key in the next line, you still might have to look through the whole output following this user ID/subkey -- so look through the whole `gpg --list-sigs [key-id]` output, find the subkey, and see if there's a self-signature line below.

In the example output for my own key, you can easily see that each `uid` or `sub` line is followed by a signature issued by the primary key itself, confirming all of them are self-signed.

```
$ gpg --list-sigs a4ff2279 |grep -EA1 '^(sub|uid)'
uid                            Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
sig 3        0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2012-12-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
--
uid                            Jens Erat <jens.erat@fsfe.org>
sig 3        0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2012-12-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
--
uid                            Jens Erat <jens.erat@uni-konstanz.de>
sig 3        0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2012-12-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
--
uid                            Jens Erat <jabber@jenserat.de>
sig 3        0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2012-12-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
--
uid                            Jens Erat <email@jenserat.de>
sig 3        0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2012-12-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
--
uid                            [jpeg image of size 12899]
sig 3        0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2012-12-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
--
sub   2048R/0x9FF7E53ACB4BD3EE 2013-01-23 [expires: 2023-01-21]
sig          0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2013-01-23  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
sub   2048R/0x5C88F5D83E2554DF 2013-01-23 [expires: 2023-01-21]
sig          0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2013-01-23  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
sub   4096R/0x8E78E44DFB1B55E9 2014-03-26 [expires: 2017-03-25]
sig          0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2014-03-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
sub   4096R/0xCC73B287A4388025 2014-03-26 [expires: 2017-03-25]
sig          0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2014-03-26  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
sub   4096R/0x382D23D4C9773A5C 2014-11-22 [expires: 2016-11-21]
sig     P    0x4E1F799AA4FF2279 2014-11-22  Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1. Just to be sure: I ran `gpg --list-sigs [key-id] |grep -EA1 '^(sub|uid)'` and now I see two `uid / sig 3`s (for two email addresses using the same key pair) followed by a `sub / sig` line. Is that the confirmation of self-signature?

Comment: If you're not missing any `sig` line containing your key ID for a `sub` or `uid` line, you're fine. I added an example for my key.