# GPG self-signature default check level

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, pgp, gnupg

I think I understand the concept of self-signature in GPG from reading the answer to this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90514/how-to-tell-if-my-openpgp-public-key-is-self-signed). However it is not yet clear to me how check levels are assigned.

When issuing `gpg --check-sigs` one can see the list of signatures. `uid` are self-signed and assigned a check level of 3 (`sig!3`) meaning that an extensive verification of the key was performed. On the other hand, signatures on sub-keys contain no check level (`sig!`).

Why is that?

Are certificate check levels only assigned to `uid`, since they are meant to link the id with a given master key. In that case, would a sub-key be validated by following the path `sub-key > master key > uid`?

In that case, is it also true that I can never distribute my sub public key separately from the master public key itself? I envision a scenario where I could have multiple encryption keys (Is that even possible?) which I would distribute separately for different purposes.